# Htm.ActionLink Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting this exception, i am not sure if im doing it the right way either,

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The View

```
@model BattleNet.API.WoW.Character


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Character</legend>
 <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Realm)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Realm)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Realm)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
</fieldset>

}

@Html.ActionLink("Search", "WoW", "Home", new { realm = Model.Realm, chara = Model.Name }, null)
```

The error

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an  object.
Line 38: @Html.ActionLink("Search", "WoW", "Home", new { realm = Model.Realm, chara =   Model.Name }, null)
```

The controller

```
    public ActionResult WoW(string realm, string chara)
    {
        var getchar = client.GetCharacter(realm, chara);

        return View(getchar);
    }
```

Any hints on what im doing wrong here would be greatly appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the third argument is `object routeValues`

```
@Html.ActionLink("TextToBeDisplayed","ActionName",object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
```

so in your case it becomes

```
@Html.ActionLink("Search", "WoW",new { controller = "Home", chara = Model.Name, realm = Model.Realm  }, null)
```

Comment: I get the same exception even with the controller added :/

Comment: then i think your model contains empty values, try passing some static string to `chara = "Name"` and `realm = "realm" `  and see if it hits the actionresult

Comment: I think its me thats just silly here actually, i should use ajax.actionlink shouldent i? theres no point using a model, i dont know why i did that, i just need a static search pages that directs to the controller with the paramaters, really sorry!